# How to ssh to a server and get CPU and memory details?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script where i want to ssh to a server and get the cpu and memory details data of that displayed as a result. I’m using the help of `top` command here.

Script line:

```
ssh -q user@host -n “cd; top -n 1 | egrep ‘Cpu|Mem|Swap’”
```

But the result is

```
TERM environment variable is not set.
```

I had checked the same in the server by entering `set | grep TERM` and got result as `TERM=xterm`

Please someone help me on this. Many thanks.

Comment: I recommend using something other than `top` to gather this information. [`dmidecode`](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/), for example, will provide more detail, more consistently across platforms. That's not related to your SSH problems, but using a different tool might help you avoid having to learn about how terminals work in ssh. :-)

Comment: I dont have provision to Install anything on the server though :/ Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: If you're in Linux with `procfs` mounted, you might parse `/proc/{cpu,mem}info`. Of course, that's highly system-dependent, and not really a `bash` question .. unless you have questions about HOW to process it, and include the code you're trying to use in your question.

Comment: How do we do that? Any code snippet in hand? Thanks very much.

Comment: I can't suggest when I don't know what you're after. Post your own attempt, along with your expected results, and we'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it..!! Need to make a small modification for the below script line.**

```
ssh -t user@host -n "top -n 1 | egrep 'Cpu|Mem|Swap'"
```

Instead of `-t` we need to give `-tt`. It worked for me.

To execute command top after ssh’ing. It requires a tty to run. Using -tt it will enable a force pseudo-tty allocation.

Thanks stony for providing me a close enough answer!! :)

Answer (score 2):

`top` need an environment. You have to add the parameter `-t` to get the result:

```
ssh -t user@host -n "top -n 1 | egrep 'Cpu|Mem|Swap'"
```

Comment: showing different error.
`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
TERM environment variable not set.`

Comment: Thanks for this Stony. I used -tt instead of -t. And it worked. -t gave me same error. But thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the top `-b` flag:

```
ssh -q user@host -n "cd; top -bn 1 | egrep 'Cpu|Mem|Swap'"
```

This tells top to run non-interactively, and [is intended for this sort of use](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top).

Comment: Didnt work, still saying `TERM environment variable not set.`

Comment: Hmm. What's the OS of `host` and what version of top is it running? I just tested with centOS and Ubuntu (16.04) target machines (each using `procps-ng version 3.3.10`) and didn't get that error (although I _do_ get the error if I don't include the `b` flag)

Comment: OS version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9. I'm not sure of how to check the version of top used though :/